# GNURadio Companion gave me Python3 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I followed the tutorial for Gnu Radio called, "Guided Tutorial GNU Radio in C++".
Link: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_C%2B%2B
After some trouble with other errors, I have finally gotten the module to appear in Gnu Radio Companion. I tried to follow the image given in the tutorial and I received this error:

```
File "/home/Username/top_block.py", line 77

self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32k
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was wondering , what I need to do. Any help?

Comment: The problem is likely on the previous line of code (which you didn't show us).  It is missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: Also, `32k` is not a valid value.

Comment: Well, I am using Gnuradio Companion and that was the error it gave me. I was not sure I can make edits to the python file it made. Also I placed, 32000 but on the module it says 32k. Is there a way for me to change that?

Comment: If 32k is  expected, it is a string , you need to enclose it with single or double quotes `'32k'` or `"32k"`. Without previous lines of code, we can only speculate.

Comment: @MarioM if you use 32000, or 32e3, or 3.2e4, it will work. The way a number is displayed is not the same as the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"32k" isn't valid python. You need to use 32000, 32e3 or something that's valid python in these fields!